# Eclipse/Pydev: How to customise tab length for different file types?

Tags: python, html, eclipse, pydev, code-formatting

I am wondering how to set different tab length depending on my file type?

For instance:
I'm editing two files at the same time: .py and .html.
In my .py file Tab inserts 4 spaces, but when I'm typing in .html it inserts 2 spaces.

Comment: Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors. There's an option for the displayed tab width and whether to use spaces instead of tabs. PyDev's editor will override them with its own settings that you can find under Window->Preferences->PyDev->...

Comment: Thanks Tom, setting overall tab length is clear. But my question was how to customize this setting depending on type of the file I am editing...